# Div gets hidden on IOS, but not in Android

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a funny issue that I have spent hours on. It looks like it has something to do with IOS Webkit since it only happens on IOS (Firefox, Chrome), but never on Android or Windows (also Firefox, Chrome). Because it only happens on a mobile phone it is difficult to debug.

I have a very specific div that does not render, but only sometimes. I have not been able to pin point when it renders and when not ... but I can change dom elements outside of it and then sometimes it works. This is a single page application and the dom gets manipulated via javascipt.

The divs above it works fine

I have attached an image of the div in question from my windows chrome machine.

[image]